# Combine rows of data frame in R using colMeans?

Tags: r, rows, mean

I'm impressed by the number of "how to combine rows/columns" threads, but even more by the fact that none of these was particularly helpful or at least not applicable to my issue.

My data look like this:

```
MyData<-data.frame("id" = c("a","a","b"),
                   "value1_1990" = c(5,NA,1),
                   "value2_1990" = c(5,NA,2),
                   "value1_2000" = c(2,1,1),
                   "value2_2000" = c(2,1,2),
                   "value1_2010" = c(NA,9,1),
                   "value2_2010" = c(NA,9,2))
```

What I want to do is to combine the two rows where `id=="a"` for columns `MyData[,(2:7)]` using base R's `colMeans`.

**What it looks like:**

```
  id value1_1990 value2_1990 value1_2000 value2_2000 value1_2010 value2_2010
1  a           5           5           2           2          NA          NA
2  a          NA          NA           1           1           9           9
3  b           1           2           1           2           1           2
```

**What I need:**

```
  id value1_1990 value2_1990 value1_2000 value2_2000 value1_2010 value2_2010
1  a           5           5         1.5         1.5           9           9
2  b           1           2           1           2           1           2
```

**What I tried (among numerous other things):**

```
MyData[nrow(MyData)+1, 2:7] = colMeans(MyData[which(MyData$id=="a"),(2:7)],na.rm=T) # to combine values from rows where id=="a"
MyData$id<-ifelse(is.na(MyData$id),"NewRow",MyData$id) # to replace "<NA>" in the id-column of the newly created row by "NewRow".
```

This works, except for the fact that...

1. ...it turns all other existing id's into numeric values (and I don't want to let the second line of code -- the ifelse-statement -- touch any of the existing id's, which is why I wrote `else==MyData$id`).
2. ...this is not particulary fancy code. Is there a one-line-of-code-solution that does the trick? I saw other approaches using `aggregate()` but this didn't work for me.

Comment: `library(dplyr); MyData %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
` With `aggregate` try `aggregate(.~id, MyData, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = "na.pass")`

Comment: Gotta love `{dplyr}` but this returns something that looks somewhat different from my original data frame. "A tibble: 2x7" and then the first line tells me that id is a <fctr> and all other variables are <dbl>. Thank you but how do I "keep the old format"?

Comment: @RonakShah's `aggregate` keeps the old format.

Comment: Right, just saw his update. That way it works with `aggregate` quite nicely! Still confused by the fact that for one, what I tried messed with my `id` and, for another, `dplyr` messed with my format.

Comment: If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll definitely upvote. Would be amazed if there's somone who can make sense of the two things I mentioned in my last comment. -- If, on the other hand, you think this is too much of a duplicate, I'll of course delete the question.

Comment: Have you used dplyr before? A `tibble` is the standard data storage format for `dplyr` functions. I'm not sure if they are automatically turned into one by the code supplied by @RonakShah, but its normal and doesn't "mess" with the data. Maybe you want to read into tibbles [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html)

Comment: @FabianHabersack I absolutely second Dom42's comment. `dplyr` most certainly does not "mess" with your data. If anything, if shows you the content of your data in a more informative way and among other things, `dplyr` methods involving `tibble`s are generally more "type-safe", faster and more consistent than their base R equivalent. If you don't like `tibble`s, just recast `as.data.frame`.

Comment: Recasting `as.data.frame` worked fine, and now that I read about `tibble`s, I must say they are pretty neat... as is `dplyr`. Will use it more often. That said, do you have any idea why my initial "solution" didn't work the way I wanted?

Comment: @RonakShah @RuiBarradas @Dom42 @MauritsEvers Suppose my `id`has something like "a1" and "a2" in it and I want combine both because it's basically the same, how would I do this using `dplyr`? My thought was that this renders `group_by` useless and I would need to select "a1" and "a2" (or "80073" and "70655" for that purpose) explicitly. Do you know how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Possible solution:

```
MyData %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Sure, this is what I did, and additionally I wrote `as.data.frame()` around it to recast data frame (instead of tibble). Just for future referece if anyone is interested or faced with a similar problem. But credits, of course, to all of you who have already commented underneath my question and provided more than one very helpful solution.